# Computing directly nth Fibonacci term without finding previous terms using binet's formula. (in O(1) time)

Tags: python, algorithm, fibonacci, fibonacci-heap

```
from math import sqrt

n = int(input())
phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2

fib_n = round((phi**n))

print(fib_n)
```

The above-mentioned code is not correct, it gives some nearer value to fib_n.

```
from math import sqrt

n = int(input())
phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2

fib_n = round((phi**n)/sqrt(5))

print(fib_n)
```

This code works absolutely perfect after dividing by sqrt(5) in the 6th line.

My doubts are:

> 1. What is the significance of dividing by sqrt(5) and why only sqrt(5) and not any other number?
> 2. Can I solve the same thing using the floor or ceiling (or any other) and without dividing by root(5)?

Any help/guidance/resources are heavily appreciated!

Comment: `round(phi**5)` is 11. It's neither "correct fib_n - 1" or "correct fib_n + 1".

Comment: @PaulHankin I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong formula.
The formula should be:

```
from math import sqrt

n = int(input())
phi1 = (1 + sqrt(5))/2
phi2 = (1 - sqrt(5))/2

fib_n = (pow(phi1, n) - pow(phi2, n)) / sqrt(5)

print(fib_n)
```

The sqrt(5) comes out of the proof: [Proof](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/a-closed-form-of-the-fibonacci-sequence)
Basically, the sqrt(5) comes from solving the partial fractions

Side note: pow(phi, n) is usually more efficient than phi ** n and it can also compute mods. pow(phi, n, m) gives (phi ** n) % m

Comment: +1 What you give is the correct mathematical formula. However, note that pow(phi2, n) is very close to 0 as n gets larger, so that's why approximating it using round(pow(phi1, n))/sqrt(5) will give you the correct results too for larger n. And that happens to give correct results for smaller n as well, so in practice, that can be used. See the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding). And since OP mentioned Binet formula, the rounding version is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @justhalf @mattyx17 does ```(phi**n)/sqrt(5)``` always give correct answer? because of its showing deviation for n > = 71.

Comment: @hack3r_0m `(phi**n)/sqrt(5)` is an approximation. The correct mathematical formula is `((((1 + sqrt(5))/2) ** n) + (((1 - sqrt(5))/2)**n)) / sqrt(5)`. As @justhalf mentioned, ((1-sqrt(5))/2)**n goes to 0 as n gets large so in some cases is ignored